# Change tiny int in datagridview with checkbox

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, checkbox, datagridview

I'm populating DataGridView with data from MySQL database, one of the values was set to tiny int (boolean), I would like it to look like a checkbox in DGV instead of 0 and 1, how can I do this?

My code for pushing data in DGV.

```
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(conStr);
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
myConn.Open(); //da.Fill(ds, sTable); da.Update(ds, sTable); myConn.Close();

ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, sTable);
myConn.Close();

dataGridView1.Refresh();

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
dataGridView1.DataMember = sTable;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

I managed to change my cell in to a checkbox like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
}
```

, but I think it's not happy that it gets 0 and 1 instead of true and false.

Apparently it works as intended, but i get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void AddOutOfOfficeColumn()
{
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
 {
     column.HeaderText = ColumnName.OutOfOffice.ToString();
     column.Name = ColumnName.OutOfOffice.ToString();
     column.AutoSizeMode = 
        DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
     column.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
     column.ThreeState = true;
     column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
     column.CellTemplate.Style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
 }

 DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, column);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value != null)
{
this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7] = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
}
}
```

This fixed it for me nicely, apparently program showed an error because it thought it was a null.